# Lowest double positive value - can cout change its value?

Tags: c++, double, precision, cout, ieee

Consider two following pieces of code - the only difference between them is a single cout which prints the value eps: 
http://ideone.com/0bEeHz - here the program enters and infinite loop since after the cout eps changes value to 0

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double tmp = 1.;
    double eps;
    while(tmp != 0) {
        eps = tmp;
        tmp /= 2.;
    }
    if(eps == 0) {
        std::cout << "(1)eps is zero!\n";
    }
    std::cout << "eps before: " << eps;
    if(eps == 0) {
        std::cout << "(2)eps is zero!\n";
    }

    while(eps < 1.) {
        tmp = eps;
        eps *= 2.;
        if(tmp == eps) {
            printf("wtf?\n");
        }
    }

    std::cout << "eps after: " << eps;
}
```

http://ideone.com/pI4d30 - here I've commented out the cout.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double tmp = 1.;
    double eps;
    while(tmp != 0) {
        eps = tmp;
        tmp /= 2.;
    }
    if(eps == 0) {
        std::cout << "(1)eps is zero!\n";
    }
    //std::cout << "eps before: " << eps;
    if(eps == 0) {
        std::cout << "(2)eps is zero!\n";
    }

    while(eps < 1.) {
        tmp = eps;
        eps *= 2.;
        if(tmp == eps) {
            printf("wtf?\n");
        }
    }

    std::cout << "eps after: " << eps;
}
```

Hence, one single cout changes program logic dramatically and very surprisingly. Why is that?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on G++ 4.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a case of Section 5 (Expressions), paragraph 11

> The values of the floating operands and the results of floating expressions **may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type**; the types are not changed thereby.

at work, cf. [this variation](http://ideone.com/HM472Q) of the original code.

```
while(tmp != 0) {
    eps = tmp;
    tmp /= 2.;
}
```

Calculations and comparisons performed at extended precision. The loop runs until `eps` is the smallest positive extended value (probably the 80-bit x87 extended type).

```
if(eps == 0) {
    std::cout << "(1)eps is zero!\n";
}
```

Still at extended precision, `eps != 0`

```
std::cout << "eps before: " << eps;
```

For the conversion to a string to print, `eps` is stored and converted to `double` precision, resulting in 0.

```
if(eps == 0) {
    std::cout << "(2)eps is zero!\n";
}
```

Yes, now it is.